# Expose actions from a React and Redux based npm library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a library (tool) which I would like to publish on `npm`. The tool is built with React and is using Redux as internal state management library.

I would like to allow other developers, when using my tool as an `npm` module, to be able to add data programmatically. However, I would not like the data to be passed down via `props` to my React component. Instead, I would like to somehow expose `actions` that the dev could call in their own React components that would then call the appropriate reducers in my `npm` module.

Is there a pattern that is recommended to achieve something like this?